# Difference in accessing props after change in redux store between React class component and React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I`m having a problem in understanding why in a Class based component vs Functional component the same steps yield a different result. Below I have an example that presents this difference.

```
   class Test extends Component {
      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
 
            await this.props.saveUserDetailsAction(values);

            const { error } = this.props; // expected modified prop 

            if (!error.status) {
              this.props.router.push("/route");
            } 
        });
      };
    }

const mapStateToProps = ({ app }) => ({
 error: app.error
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  saveUserDetailsAction,
};

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
)(Test);
```

The current error prop inside the class component reflects the changes in the redux store after the async function *saveUserDetailsAction* has completed, in this case dispatching an action if the request fails.

Accessing the error props after the *saveUserDetailsAction* function shows the updated prop.

The same code written as a functional component does not yield the same result. Accessing the error prop after the *saveUserDetailsAction* function completed doesn't reflect the change in the store yet.

```
  const Test = (props) => {
      const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {     

            await props.saveUserDetailsAction(values);

            const { error } = props;  // unchanged prop when accessed here

            if (!error.status) {
              props.router.push("/route");
            }
        });
      };
    }

const mapStateToProps = ({ app }) => ({
 error: app.error
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  saveUserDetailsAction,
};

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
)(Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

To my point of view, it's an anti-pattern, you need to wait for another cycle to get the correct error props. Functional component is the right behavior.
What you need to do is find a way to return error here :

```
const { error } = await props.saveUserDetailsAction(values);
```

Redux store error variable can still be used in another component

Other way to do it is to use a `useEffect(() => {}, [error])` and to distinguish 3 states "No Submitted Yet", "Submitted without error", "Submitted with error" but i don't recommend it